# Which national cloud deployments support Delta queries?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

This Microsoft's documentation page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments indicates that support for Delta queries against Microsoft Graph API varies across different resources on each national cloud deployment.

I would like to know exactly which deployments support Delta queries against Microsoft Graph API, but I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, we don't currently document which clouds support delta query.

If you're willing to do a bit of investigating, I can show you a trick to see not only which clouds support delta query but also which specific endpoints support delta query.

You can send `metadata` requests to each cloud like https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn/v1.0/$metadata or https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata. Note that these requests don't require an access token in the header so you can actually just open these links in your browser.

Search this XML for `delta` and you'll see our delta function definitions.  For example, the following says that the user collection (`GET /users`) supports delta query.

[image]

This one means that groups supports delta query.

[image]