# How to correctly determine if a given Azure AD region supports delta queries?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on an Azure AD integration that works with multiple regions. Ideally I'd use delta queries whenever possible, however as not all regions support delta queries I have a check for delta query support as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779703/8450595). However recently the check broke. It turns out that the `microsoft.` prefix has been removed from the return type (ie `microsoft.graph.group` became `graph.group`). I can't find any information about this change in the changelog and I'd prefer to make the check as future-proof as possible, so my question is - what value should I check for? Currently my intent is to check for the support of delta query for a type that ends with `graph.group` and a type that ends with `graph.user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and apparently the $metadata endpoint returns OData CSDL metadata. As per the [documentation on the Schema element](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc406397947), the Schema element must include a Namespace attribute and may include an Alias attribute. [The nominal types may be qualified with either](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Nominal_Types). With that in mind one could check the defined namespace and alias and then figure out the possible ways to refer to the user and group types.

Answer (score 1):

There seems not to be a change log for Microsoft Graph metadata.

But there is a history list for Microsoft Graph metadata.

See history for [V1.0 metadata](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/commits/master/v1.0_metadata.xml) and [Beta metadata](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/commits/master/beta_metadata.xml).

For V1.0, the `microsoft.` prefix was removed in [the Jan 28 version](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/commit/0f697535b1c6ed0be957b42515828c04d8686d6c#diff-e34459d76b3a635d414d3549ff656c4c). And for Beta it was removed in [the Feb 26 version](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/commit/31efaa40ceb84162ecdb0f70d43c5565557f1d3a#diff-1f82c09660ae27359655006d82393127).

Now that it has been changed, I believe it will continue to maintain this version (without the `Microsoft.` prefix). So you should check `ReturnType Type="Collection(graph.user)"` and `ReturnType Type="Collection(graph.group)"` currently.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer! The commits are very helpful in tracking down the change. I've noticed something - the Schema element declares the namespace and the alias. Taking a look at this change I believe the type names are prefixed with the alias if present and with the namespace if not. Do you know if this assumption is correct? If so, the safest way would be to check those attributes on the Schema element.

Comment: @Petrov I think what you said makes sense. But I don't have related official information about it. In any case, I believe this kind of big update will last for a long time. It will be helpful to keep an eye on this history list.